# Soft link is not found, even though it's clearly there

Tags: linux, bash, macos, symlink

First, I create a softlink to the executable `mesher` and I confirm that it's actually there:

```
[me@mine mesh_subdir] ln -s mesher ../mesher
[me@mine mesh_subdir] cd ../
[me@mine project_home] ls
file1 file2 mesher
```

Seems fine.

Now, I'd like to execute `mesher`:

```
[me@mine project_home] ./mesher
-bash: ./mesher: No such file or directory
```

Why? I clearly see a file `mesher` in `project_home`. I also try to press tab twice to see all the options, and `mesher` never shows up. In the meanwhile, `cat` on `file1` and `file2` work properly.

**Why is `mesher` not properly found in my filesystem, and what can I do?**

(It's a bash shell on OS X Sierra.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symlinks can have relative paths.
The line `ln -s mesher ../mesher` means "make a symlink in `../mesher` to a file named `mesher` in the current directory. Now, when you do `cd ..`, the current directory changes -- changing the target of the link.

Try `ls -l mesher` instead of `ls`, and you will see the problem: the `mesher` symlink points to itself.

Instead try it the other way round: Linking from the directory where the symlink should reside:

```
cd ..
ln -s mesh_subdir/mesher mesher
```

By the way, you can omit the link's name if source and target have the same name: `ln -s mesh_subdir/mesher` would be sufficient here.

Answer (score 1):

because it's created relatively at the target:

```
ln -s dirname/mesher ../mesher
```

also ls -l shows broken link

```
cd ..
ls -l mesher
```